# A colored ball problem - $2$

Tags: probability

Say you have $2n+2b$ balls where $2n$ balls are colored white, $b$ balls are colored blue and $b$ balls are colored red.

You have two urns. You randomly choose $n+b$ balls and throw in urn $1$ while you place the remaining $n+b$ balls in urn $2$.

What is the probability that the blue balls and red balls are in separate urns?

I am most interested in case $\frac{n}b\rightarrow\infty$ such as $b=n^{\frac1c}$ with $c>1$ being fixed and in case $\frac{n}b\rightarrow c$ such as $b={\frac nc}$ with $c>1$.

Comment: Please link to the original question where you asked part of this question before to avoid unnecessary duplication of efforts. More generally speaking, please give more thought to how your actions affect others and how you can make more efficient use of this site, both for yourself and for others. Also, why did you again tag this question with [tag:polya-urn-model] after failing to answer my comment under the other question why this is relevant?

Comment: I don't see how this can be regarded as a generalized Pólya urn model. I've removed the tag from both questions and improved the tag description to clarify the central feature of the Pólya urn model. If you disagree and insist that this has to do with Pólya urn models, please explain in more detail.

Comment: Actually I think you are right. For some reason I *plainly* thought increasing number of colors would make it a generalized polya urn model.

Comment: Why did you delete the reference to the original question after adding it?

Comment: There is no point. This is a more detailed problem.

Comment: How do you mean, there is no point? You ask a question; two people invest their time and effort into providing you with a correct answer; you then ask another closely related question, the answer to which obviously needs to build on the answer to the other question, and you see no point in linking to that answer so that people don't have to redo the work that others have already done?

Comment: Arul. This question was flagged for many reasons. That lead me to take a look at your history of questions. I noticed several groups of **deleted** questions that seemed to be closely related. This is definitely NOT the way we operate on this site. It is natural, and a good sign, that your questions evolve as you develop a better understanding of the question. But the way to share this development with others is to EDIT  and add the details to the first version. It is a good idea to mark the additions like **More details - Sept 7th**. That way nobody will wonder

Comment: (cont'd) about possible answer(s) to an earlier version. There are many good reasons for this rule. 1) It is more respectful to the efforts of others trying to help you (they don't need to duplicate each others work when they clearly see what others have done). 2) It is better for site hygiene. There is no way to permanently delete the earlier versions your questions. Anything that is deleted can also be undeleted. Therefore by deleting and reasking you generate a lot of orphaned, deleted questions. Nothing good can come from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the explicit answer received in the previous version of this question, which was $2\frac{{2n}\choose{n}}{{2n+2b}\choose {n+b}}$, and assuming $n\rightarrow\infty$, you can use the Stirling approximation for the factorial to get $2\sqrt{\frac{n+b}{n}}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2b}\simeq\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2b-1}$.

Comment: This works for the first case in the question, $b=n^{\frac1c}$. In the second case, $b=n/c$, a factor $\sqrt{1+\frac1c}$ survives in the limit $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in answers to your original question, the probability of separation is

$$
\frac{2\binom{2n}n}{\binom{2(n+b)}{n+b}}\;.
$$

Both binomial coefficients are [central binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient), which for $n\to\infty$ are asymptotic to

$$
{2n \choose n} \sim \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}\;.
$$

Since $n+b\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$, the probability of separation is asymptotic to

$$
\frac{2\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}}{\frac{4^{n+b}}{\sqrt{\pi(n+b)}}}=\frac2{4^b\sqrt{1+b/n}}\;.
$$

for $n\to\infty$. For $n/b=c$ fixed, this goes to $0$ as $n\to\infty$, since $b\to\infty$. Likewise for $b=n^{\frac1c}$ for any $c\gt1$. In the latter case, $b/n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, so in this case the probability of separation converges to

$$
\frac2{4^b}=2^{-(2b+1)}\;.
$$

Comment: Yes. I think correct scaling for other case is $$\frac{2^{-(2b+1)}}{\sqrt{1+n^{\frac{1}c-1}}}.$$

Comment: @Arul: I'm not sure what you mean by "scaling" here, and I'm not sure why you're replacing one expression that mixes $b$ and $n$ by another expression that mixes $b$ and $n$. Anyway, for what it's worth, your expression, like mine, is asymptotic to the probability of separation for $n\to\infty$ in the case $b=n^{\frac1c}$.

Comment: @Arul: I don't understand your use of "asymptotic" and "parametrized" in that sentence. Our expressions are equal, as they only differ by substitution of the fixed relationship $b=n^{\frac1c}$. Thus they are either both asymptotic or both not asymptotic, and either both exact or both not exact. They're not exact, since I used an asymptotic approximation of the central binomial coefficients in the derivation. They're both asymptotic. Yours seems a bit more complicated to me, since it involves $3$ variables rather than $2$, but other than that it's equivalent to mine.

Comment: Still it kind of does not make sense. Say you have $2n$ balls of unit weight  each and $2$ balls of weight $b$ each. You pick balls randomly so that total weight is $n+b$. Probability that you pick only one of the weight $b$ ball is $2^{-(2b+1)}$? Imagine $n=10^{100}$ while $b=10^{100}/50$

Comment: @Arul: No, you still haven't specified a distribution. I suppose that "Assume you have an uniform way to pick balls by weight." was meant to specify a distribution, but I don't see how it does. Please take the time to clearly specify the distribution you have in mind.

Comment: Assume you keep picking balls one at a time until you have $n+b$ weight. What is the probability that you have exactly $1$ ball of weight $b$ with you finally?

Comment: @Arul: Do you mean "until you have at least $n+b$ weight"? If not, what happens when I have more than $n+b$ weight?

Comment: at least $n+b$ weight is a good start

Comment: @Arul: This is a rather complicated experiment. To answer your question: It seems rather unlikely that the probability of picking one of the weight $b$ balls would come out to exactly $2^{-(2b+1)}$. If you want to ask further questions about this newly defined experiment, please post a new question; this comment space is not meant for asking completely new questions like that.